# What is the difference between "anaphora" and "deixis"?

Tags: syntax, terminology

I've been trying to understand an answer from another SE site (Japanese Language & Usage) where the answer involves the differences between anaphora and deixis. [Here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6262/1328) is the link.

What would be the difference between anaphoric and deictic usage? If possible, please provide some examples showing the differences.

Comment: By the way, _anaphora_ is a (Greek) plural noun, while _deictic_ is an adjective. If you want them both to modify _usage_ in the question, you should use _anaphoric_ instead for parallelism. And neither one needs scare quotes; they're standard terms.

Comment: The scare quotes were added by @hippietrail, probably because titles here don't seem to be able to contain italics.

Comment: I didn't intend them to be "scare" quotes, just trying to distinguish mention from use since as kaleissin says italics etc can't be used in titles. Feel free to revert or clarify in some other way.

Comment: @jlawler *Anaphora* is not a Greek neuter plural, but a feminine singular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know any Japanese, but generally, an **anaphora** is an expression that refers to something mentioned earlier in the text:

> John is tired because **he** has been working all day.
>
> Mary said the moon is made of cheese. I don't believe **that**.

*He* in the first example refers to John; *that* in the second one refers to the moon being made of cheese.

---

A **deixis** is an expression whose exact meaning varies with the context in which it is uttered.

- Who exactly is meant by *you*? That depends on who is being spoken to.
- Where is *here*? Whereever the speaker is, or where he is pointing to.
- What time will it be *in one hour*? That depends on when it is being said.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm starting to understand the difference!

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to go a bit more in depth about this.

### Deixis

Traditionally, by deixis is meant the location and identification of person, objects, events, processes and activities being talked about, or referred to, in relation to the spatiotemporal context created and sustained by the act of utterance and the participation in it, typically, of a single speaker and at least one addressee; we can analyze them this way:

1. **Person deixis:** those that are used to refer to speaker and addressee (*I, you, we*);
2. **Place deixis:** those that refer to spatial context (*here, there*);
3. **Time deixis:** these that refer to temporal context (*now, then, verb tense markers*);
4. **Discourse deixis:** those that refer to parts of unfolding discourse (*next, below, furthermore*);
5. **Social deixis:** those that encode aspects of the social relationship between speaker and addressee (*Her Majesty*);
6. **Perceptual deixis:** *There's Harry*.

Deixis concerns the use of certain linguistic expressions to locate entities in spatiotemporal, social and discursive context. First and second person pronouns, demonstratives, tense, certain place and time adverbials, verbs such as *come, go, bring, take* and *fetch*. Such deictic expressions encode specific aspects of the speech event and **cannot be interpreted unless contextual parameters are taken into account**.

Without physical context we cannot interpret utterances like:

> I'll meet you over there.
>   See you tomorrow.
>   Will be back in 10 minutes.
>   You, you and you, come over here.
>   He does not like that.
>   Put that here and then move this over there.

Deictic expressions refer to a deictic field of language whose zero point is fixed by the person who is speaking, the place of utterance and the time of utterance (I, here, now, respectively, etc). **Deictic constructions construct the speaker as the deictic center**.

### Anaphora and Cataphora

**Anaphora**, along with **cataphora** and other devices, belong to the so-called **Patterns of reduction**. In other words they allow you to say less, but still keep sense in your utterances.

- Anaphora = reference backward
- Cataphora = reference forward

Anaphora is a lower expenditure of cognitive effort for recovering the conceptual content of the co-referring expression (more efficient) - the identity of the content is made plain in advance. Cataphora's processing requires the creation of a temporarily empty slot until the required content is supplied (low efficiency): it is often used to generate uncertainty and to intensify receiver's interest (effectiveness).

### The difference

The Anaphora, in the linguistics sense, makes use of deictic expressions:

> **Sam** went home because **he** was tired.

"He" is the anaphora expression referring to "Sam", but it's also a deictic expression, i.e. it changes according to the context/subject.

Deixis, on the other hand, is not necessarily related to anaphora. For example, there's no anaphora in this sentence:

> **You**, **you** and **you**, come over here.

Those are just deictic expressions referring to 3 different subjects, but no anaphora.

Comment: Very simple distinction: First and Second Person are Deixis, Third Person is Anaphora.

Comment: Oh, and if anybody is interested, Fillmore's _1971 Santa Cruz Deixis Lectures_ are available [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Comment: Thanks for this information, it makes it very clear to understand my answer now.