# Types of Deixis and Anaphoric and Endophoric references help?

Tags: deixis

So basically I have this text and it states:

> "Our *study* shows ..."
>
> While it only focused on ..., the findings are also thought to hold true for other ...
>
> **It** involved only college students, ...

(Certain words are omitted for a reason)

Now the 'It' is a deixis, and it is assumed that it refers to the study previously mentioned, so am I correct in assuming it is an anaphoric reference even though there is some text in between which focuses on the findings of the study rather than the study? Or is it a different type of deixis altogether?

Comment: It is a fine question! Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this *it* is certainly anaphoric (provided that it refers back to *our study* or some other element in the text). There is no need for an anaphor to come immediately or soon after a previous element in the text: as long as it refers to *some* element that was mentioned earlier in the text or discourse, it's anaphoric.

There are several definitions of deixis, I believe, but a widely accepted one is an element whose meaning or reference depends on something in the context. Wikipedia agrees. Then anaphora is a kind of deixis. The narrower definition has deixis as something that refers to an *extra-linguistic* context; then anaphora would not be deixis.

Comment: See the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html) for more on that subject.

Comment: By the way, anaphora is not deixis. Anaphora refers to a part previously mentioned in the text, deixis usually refers to extralinguistic elements. Anaphora, along with cataphora, is an [endophoric reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endophora). See also [this previous answer](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/2308/111). :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Well, there appear to be different definitions of deixis. I remember once being taught deixis was extralinguistic, as you say; but Wikipedia and your own answer(!) seem to favour the broader definition, where it can refer to something linguistic or discursive: *"He" is the anaphora expression referring to "Sam", but it's also a deictic expression, i.e. it changes according to the context/subject.* Wikipedia has a section *Anaphora* in the article *Deixis*. Edited my answer to include both definitions.

Comment: @Cerberus Sometimes they match, but my point was that they're not one the subset of the other. Both "refer" to something and can coexist, yes, but anaphora is not a subset of deixis. This is what I felt was ambiguous in your answer (according to my studies at least). :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Okay, well, according to some definition(s), anaphora is considered a subset of deixis...

Answer (score 0):

Name : Buthina Mohammed Ahmed Alkamel. **Deixis**.

Definition of deixis: is referring noun using to refer or pointing for proximal terms  and distal terms.

This pointing is called a dectic expression, the dectic expression sometimes is    called as indexicals.

For example:

1. He put that here.
2. I want this now.

The first example uses **three** deixis, the first one is pronoun "he" which refers person, the second is demonstrative pronoun "that" which refers to something  is distant from the speaker, and the last deixis is "here" which refers to place.

The second example uses **three** deixis, the first one is pronoun "I" which refers to the speaker, the second is demonstrative pronoun "this" refer to something be near of speaker, the last deixis is "now" which refers to the time.

THE DEIXIS DIVIDED TO TWO KINDS

1. Proximal term: something is near or close of the speaker, such as (this,here,now).
   "situated nearest to point of attachment or origin"
2. Distal term: is  the opposite of proximal, something is far of the speaker. Such as (that,there,then).
   "situated farthest from point of attachment or origin, as of a limb or bone"